# How insert space before certain data?

Tags: javascript

I have next type of string

```
const string = 'some text some text in44 some text'
```

How I can transform it to next, with regexp / js code

```
const string = 'some text some text in 44 some text'
```

So, I just need insert space before every number value in string that comes after in.
Does it possible to implement?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex combined with the method `replaceAll` to do what you require easily, for example you can use a regex as follow:

```js
// Match all the numbers composed by at least 1 digit, preceded by at least 1 character
const regex = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/g;
let string = 'some text some text in44 some text'
// Replace all the match as "First group" (the characters matched by the '[a-zA-Z]+') + space + "Second group" (the digits matched by the \d+)
string = string.replaceAll(regex, '$1 $2');
```